# dojo how to get id in innerHTML?

Tags: dojo

I am studying the dojo. I do not know how to solve the situation.
I am dynamically generating the tabContainer and those inside the ContentPane, GridContainer, Portlet is available. I GirdContainer access to the object can be But I can not access Portlet far. Because all things are made ​​dynamically created is the string. I want to access the object id,title of the Portlet and other information. Ask for advice.

my code

```
 function(data){
   ++gridCounter;
   var cont='';
   cont+='<div dojoType="dojox.layout.GridContainer" class="test" doLayout="true" id="gc'+gridCounter+'" region="center" hasResizableColumns="false" opacity="0.3"  nbZones="1" allowAutoScroll="false" withHandles="true" dragHandleClass="dijitTitlePaneTitle" minChildWidth="200" minColWidth="10" style="height:50%;">';
   for(var i=0;i<data.Vidgets.length;i++){
   cont+='<div dojoType="dojox.widget.Portlet"  title="'+data.Vidgets[i].name+'" closable="false">'+data.Vidgets[i].name+'</div>';
   }
   cont+='</div>';
   cont+='<div dojoType="dojox.layout.GridContainer" class="test" doLayout="true" id="gc'+(++gridCounter)+'" region="center" hasResizableColumns="false" opacity="0.3" nbZones="3" allowAutoScroll="false" withHandles="true" dragHandleClass="dijitTitlePaneTitle" minChildWidth="200" minColWidth="40" style="height:50%;">';
   cont+='<div dojoType="dojox.widget.Portlet"  title="vidget5" closable="false">vidget5</div>';
   cont+='</div>';
   cont+='<div dojoType="dojox.layout.GridContainer" class="test" doLayout="true" id="gc'+(++gridCounter)+'" region="center" hasResizableColumns="false" opacity="0.3" nbZones="2" allowAutoScroll="false" withHandles="true" dragHandleClass="dijitTitlePaneTitle" minChildWidth="200" minColWidth="60" style="widht:50%;">';
   cont+='<div dojoType="dojox.widget.Portlet"  title="vidget6" closable="false">vidget6</div>';
   cont+='</div>';
   addTab(data.FormName,cont);
 }
 function addTab(name,cont){
  var tab=new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        title:name,
        id:''+name,
        content:cont,
        class:'tab',
        closable: true,
        onClose:function(){
            return confirm('relly want to remove?');
        }
        });
    dijit.byId('tabContainer').addChild(tab);
 }
```

when i was writing the code, i could access to GridContainer object.

```
 var tabs=registry.byId("tabContainer");
 var cPane=tabs.get("selectedChildWidget");
 var grid=cPane.getChildren()[0];->access to GridContainer
```

But i can't access to Portlet object because it was string(innerHTML)
i want to aceess to Portlet object. plz help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like any layout widget the `dojox/layout/GridContainer` also has a method `getChildren()`. So if you can access the `GridContainer`, you can use the `getChildren()` method again to retrieve the children of that widget (which are the portlets).

For example:

```js
var tabs = registry.byId("tabContainer");
var cPane = tabs.get("selectedChildWidget");
var grid = cPane.getChildren()[0]; // Access to GridContainer
var portlets = grid.getChildren(); // Returns an array of all portlets
                                   //  inside the GridContainer
```

Comment: I'm really stupid. Why did not I think of other ways. always gave you good advice to me. Thank you so so much. You are the best.

Comment: Additional questions. I getDescendants () was used. The use of this method Is not that nice?

Comment: `getDescendants()` will return all children (nested, on all levels), while `getChildren()` will only return immediate children. So if you would use `cPane.getDescendants()`, you would get all portlets as well. But if you only need the portlets inside the `GridContainer`, `getChildren()` works fine.